# Is there a way to jump to record I have searched for and still display values less and greater than the value I searched for?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Please assist. Instead of filtering I want to find a value for example value 10 and jump to that value 10 but still display values that are less than 10 and greater than 10. This value is a size of something so if I don't have size 10 I want to be able to see available sizes greater or less as they may suite my need. Values are sorted in ascending order So instead of filtering the data I am jumping to value 10 and should be able to scroll up or down to see values less or greater than my value. If The value 10 is not available it can jump to the next greater value. My code below is not selecting the value I searched for, it is just displaying from zero.

```
Sub search()
    Try
        DataGridRecords.Rows.Clear()
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from tblDies where  `IDSIZE` <> " & txtIdSize.Text & " ", conn)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            DataGridRecords.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("DIENUMBER"), dr.Item("DESCRIPT"), dr.Item("OLDNUMBER"), dr.Item("CODE"), dr.Item("QUANTITY"), dr.Item("IDSIZE"), dr.Item("ODSIZE"), dr.Item("HEIGHT"), dr.Item("FLANGE HT"), dr.Item("FLANGE DIA"), dr.Item("CuRef"), dr.Item("CUTEL"), dr.Item("CuContact"), dr.Item("Price-selling"), dr.Item("P/no"), dr.Item("Stoksize"), dr.Item("Material"), dr.Item("Shore"), dr.Item("DieChkd"), dr.Item("DIECOST"), dr.Item("DATE"), dr.Item("REMARKS"), dr.Item("PRREF"))
        End While
        DataGridRecords.Sort(DataGridRecords.Columns(6), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        dr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: So match() will allow the result to be less than, equal to or greater than a defined value, so you will need 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the data directly to your grid. Populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid via a `BindingSource`. If you need to sort (you should use the query by default) then set the `Sort` property. The `BindingSource` has a `Find` method that will return an index, which you can assign to its `Position` property.

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable

table.Load(myDataReader)

myBindingSource.DataSource = table
myDataGridView.DataSource = myBindingSource
```

```vb
myBindingSource.Position = myBindingSource.Find(columnName, value)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, It worked. The problem I am having now is it does not do partial search. I am searching for numbers so if the number is 123.5 and I type in 123 it doesn't search. code below gives me error (System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "%'" to type 'Double' is not valid.')              TblDiesBindingSource.Position = TblDiesBindingSource.Find("IDSIZE Like'", +(Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text) + "%'"))

Comment: @Lloyd, that's nonsensical to begin with because the first argument is a column/property name, so including an operator in it couldn't possibly work. You should have read the documentation for that method to learn how it actually works. Apart from that, the `LIKE` operator only works with text, so it can't possibly match on numbers or the like. What you could do is use the `Select` method of the underlying `DataTable` to convert the numeric data to text and do a partial match, get the ID of the first matching row and then `Find` that in your `BindingSource`.

Comment: @Lloyd, you also didn't mention anything about partial matches in your question. I would suggest that you accept this answer as resolving the question you actually asked, then ask a new question about partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

<> this symbol is for not equal try something like, Select * from tblDies where  `IDSIZE` >= ? OR `IDSIZE` <= ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, Your solution is giving me same results as my <>. it is not pointing to the value that I have searched for. If i search for value 10 it should go to 10 and still display values greater and less than 10. the key is to point on 10 which is the value I have searched for.